# Is my limited understanding of division and gcd on track?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

Hello I am trying to make sense of some beginner theorems and propositions in number theory. I am wanting to also know if what I am saying is valid or just completely wrong.

I am wanting to show that given some non zero integers m and n,

$$m=p_{1}^{r_1} \times...\times p_{k}^{r_{k}}$$
$$n=p_{1}^{s_1} \times...\times p_{k}^{s_{k}}$$

then gcd(m,n)=$$m=p_{1}^{min({s_1,}{r_1})} \times...\times p_{k}^{min({s_k},r_{k})}$$

Now what I am trying to use is that a|b if and only if when we write them out as products of primes, a and b have all the same primes but its exponents are greater than b for each respectively.

so for d to divide m  we must be able to write it as $$d=p_{1}^{q_1} \times...\times p_{k}^{q_{k}}$$ where $$q_{i} \le r_{i}$$ for all $$i \in (1,2,...,k)$$
and similar for d to divide n we must be able to do the same but with $$q_{i} \le s_{i}$$

So now can I simply just do a contradiction type argument, say for example that suppose r_1=5 and s_1=3 $$q_{1} \neq min{s_1,r_1}$$. and say $q_{1}=4$ then d wouldn't divide n and hence not a gcd etc. Does this make sense? ( and similarly for the LCM we do the same but suppose the exponent was not the max)

Comment: For $d$ to divide $m$, you need the opposite: $q_i\leq r_i$. Similarly for $n$, $q_i\leq s_i$. So if $q_i\leq s_i$ and $r_i$, then $q_i\leq \min(s_i,r_i)$.

Comment: Yea i had typo, i fixed

Comment: @ThomasAndrews does it look any better now ?

Comment: Yes, every thing seems good.  You can extend the to all m,n by allow some $r_i$ and $s_k$ to be zero.  (So p divides m but not n, would result in p being written in n's expansion but with a zero power.)